# laravel get only count from releation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have following releation in my controller and it works fine .

```
$response=Event::with('eventDetail','eventDetail.members')->get();
```

Now i need to get total members of that event.
Event has many event detail and each event detail has many members.

```
Event::with(
    ['eventDetail'=>function($query){
        $query->count();
    }])->with([
    'eventDetail.members'=>function($query){
        $query->count();
    }
    ]
)->get();
```

but still its loading all data instead of count

Answer (score 0):

Use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
Event::withCount(['eventDetail', 'eventDetail.members'])->get();
```

Comment: ,.thanks but igot  eror Call to undefined method App\Models\Event::withCount()

Comment: @vision this works by default, so it looks like you've modified something. Make sure `Event` model extends `Model` class.